# XMLHttpRequest Returns 404 Even Though File Exists

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, xml, web.py

This is what the file structure for my project looks like. Voice, Text and Template are folders.

[image: Folder structure for my project: "Voice" folder contains app.py file and folders Text and Template. Text contains voice.txt, and Template contains index.html]

I run `python app.py`, and when I go to localhost `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` I can see the `index.html` page with content piped in by `app.py`.

There's text in `index.html` that's piped in from `voice.txt`, and if I view `voice.txt` in my text editor I can see that a loop in `app.py` is successfully appending more text to it every 20 seconds.

The issue I'm having is trying to get the updated `voice.txt` text into the body of `index.html`. I'm trying to do this with XMLHttpRequest. Here's the relevant code from the  tag in `index.html`:

```
function UpdateText() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Code goes here
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        console.log(statusText);
        console.log(responseText);
    }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "../Text/voice.txt", true);
xhttp.send();

};
```

When I run that `index.html` displays properly, but when it tries to update the text I get the following error message in Terminal:

```
127.0.0.1:64013 - - [28/May/2019 00:55:10] "HTTP/1.1 GET /Text/voice.txt" - 404 Not Found
```

I could be wrong but at this point I'm fairly sure that the filepath in `xhttp.open()` should actually be a URL (this is the first time I'm using XMLHttpRequest and every tutorial I've seen just has the filename and nothing else), in which case I'm not sure how I'd link to `voice.txt`. I'm using the web.py library for this, here's the relevant section of `app.py`:

```
urls = (
"/", "index",
)

indexpath = "/Users/[USERNAME]/torch/torch-rnn/voice/Template/"
render = web.template.render(indexpath)

class index(object):
def GET(self):
    the_voice = open(voicepath, "r+").read()    
    return render.index(the_voice)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = web.application(urls, globals())
app.run()
```

I feel like the solution probably involves changing something in either the `urls` or `render` variables, but I've been going around in circles with this for hours and I'm out of ideas.

### What I've Tried

First thought I had was to throw a dummy file called also called `voice.txt` into the Template folder next to `index.html` then change the filepath in the XMLHttpRequest to reflect that, but I still got the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server *only* knows about a single URL "`/`" and will return it when asked as 'https://:8080/'. That's all you've listed as possible values in your `urls =()` bit.

So, your attempt to get, via web interface, anything else will fail. If you want to have the webserver retrieve your voice.txt file, you need to include it, or something which will match it, in `urls`, and have that class then get and send on the `voice.txt` file. (Note that files themselves aren't in a `Text` folder, they could be anywhere, as described by `myDirectory`.)

For example,

```
urls = ( "/", "index",
         "/Text/(.*)", "get_file")

class get_file(object):
    def GET(self, filename):
        the_file = open(myDirectory + '/' + filename, "r").read()
        return the_file
```

might do what you want (or give you some ideas). By using the regular expression in `urls`, any http get like '/Text/foo', '/Text/voice.txt', '/Text/ant_eater.jpg' will attempt to read the file ('foo', 'voice.txt', 'ant_eater.jpg') in the directory described by `myDirectory`, and return that file to the user.

If you're serving different types of files (as with my example) you should also set headers for the content type, but that's a different question.